# Persisting inner entities, Spring Jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa, persistence

If there is an entity object inside the entity
Accepts the value of the internal entity object including id from the outside (Controller)
After granting persistence, save the outside entity.

```
public class IssueCommentService {
    public IssueComment toEntity(Long id){
        return repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(NoContentFromRequestException::new);
    }

    public IssueComment toEntity(IssueComment notPersistIssueComment){
        if (Objects.isNull(notPersistIssueComment.getId())) {
            throw new CanNotBecomeEntityException();
        }
        return toEntity(notPersistIssueComment.getId());
    }
}

public class IssueCommentController {

    @PatchMapping(value = "")
    public ResponseEntity<IssueComment> updateCommentIssueComment(@RequestBody IssueComment issueComment) {
        String updateComment = issueComment.getComment();
        IssueComment entityIssueComment = issueCommentService.toEntity(issueComment);
        issueCommentService.updateComment(entityIssueComment, updateComment);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(issueCommentService.toEntity(entityIssueComment), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

At this time, the internal entity containing the id is persistently repeated.
What is a good way to handle it all at once?

Should the inner object be persistent every time?

Thank you for the answer in advance.

Answer (score 0):

just inner object cascadeType default